# I would like to show that all reflections in a finite reflection group $W :=\langle t_1, \ldots , t_n\rangle$ are of the form $wt_iw^{-1}.$

Tags: group-theory, geometry

I would like to show that all reflections in a finite reflection group $W := \langle t_1, \ldots , t_n\rangle$ are of the form $wt_iw^{-1}$ for some $i$ and some $w \in W$

Clearly all such elements are reflections, however it is not clear how to prove that only elements of the form $wt_iw^{-1}$ are reflections.

Note: Here reflection means a linear map on some vector space $V$ that fixes all elements in some codimension $1$ subspace of $V$, and additionally has eigenvalue $-1$.

Edit : Is this a well known result? I'm having trouble finding it anywhere other than one set of notes.

Comment: Is this occurring in $3$ dimensions, or an arbitrary number of dimensions?

Comment: There is no mention of the dimension of the vector space, so I've been trying to show the result for arbitrary dimension. Are you about to tell me that the result only holds for dimension $\leq 3$?

Comment: No, but I know a proof for dimension $3$, since there's a complete classification of finite isometry groups, and you can check that for each of them, reflections are conjugate.

Comment: Hope still remains...

Comment: What papers and/or textbooks have you consulted? Such as are listed on the Wikipedia page on reflection groups?

Comment: Whenever the group comes from a root system (types A,B,C,D,E,F,G) this follows from the fact that all reflections are w.r.t. to a hyperplane determined by a root. As all roots are conjugate to a simple root, and reflections corresponding to simple roots are exactly the $t_i$s, the claim follows in this case. The same holds for direct products if it holds for factors. The claim holds for the dihedral groups, but I can't vouch for types $H_3$ and $H_4$. It is on my "to do"-list to read Humphreys book on Coxeter groups :-/

Answer (score 0):

One does not need the classification theorem for finite reflection groups in order to prove this property. Consider the real vector space $V$ on which $W$ is acting. Recall that a W-wall in $V$ is the hyperplane fixed by a reflection in $W$. Walls divide $V$ into **chambers**, closures of chambers are fundamental domains of the action of $W$ on $V$. It follows that given a  wall $H$, there exists a chamber $C$ such that $H\cap C$ is a facet of $C$. Let $t\in W$ denote the unique reflection fixing $H$. 
Now, let $C_+$ denote the positive chamber: the standard generators $t_i$ of $W$ are reflections in the facets of $C_+$. Since $C$ is a fundamental domain, there exists $w\in W$ such that $wC_+= C$. Therefore, the conjugate element
$$
t'= w t w^{-1}
$$
fixes the wall $w^{-1}(H)$ and, hence, the facet $w^{-1}(H\cap C)\subset C_+$. Therefore, by the definition, $t'$ is one of the standard generators $t_i$ of $W$. qed