# Why are the conjugated generating reflections the only reflections of a finite reflection group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reflection

Why are the conjugated generating reflections the only reflections of a finite reflection group?

Suppose $W$ is a finite reflection group. (i.e $W$ is finite and is generated by a set of orthogonal reflections of euclidean space). I want to show that if a set of reflections $T$ generates $W$ then $\{wtw^{-1} | w \in W, t \in T\}$ consists of $\textbf{all}$ reflections of $W$.

Comment: $W$ is in general not a group, because composition of two reflections is a rotation. The way you can see this is by observing nonidentity reflections reverse orientation, so applying a reflection twice results in a map that preserves orientation, which is not a reflection. So the only reflection group that exists is $\{\text{id}, \sigma\}$ with $\sigma$ some arbitrary reflection. Now the fact you want to prove becomes evident.

Comment: Thanks for your comment M. Van. I know that W does not consist of only reflections. But I want to know why the set $\{wtw^{-1} | w \in W, t \in T\}$ does consist of all the reflections contained in $W$.

Comment: @M.Van "reflection group" is used to mean a group *generated* by reflections, not a group consisting only of reflections. By most definitions the identity is not a reflection, so in your sense there's no such thing as a reflection group.

Comment: Where did you see this, and how much about this do you know? The first few ways to prove this that come to mind require some Coxeter group theory.

Comment: It is on page $7$ of Fomin and Reading's 'Root systems and generalised associahedron'. As it is suggested as an exercise (and appears so early on!) I thought it should be proved with fairly elementary methods - but I can't think how to attack it.

Comment: I am sorry @jamesharris , I misread.

Comment: Try this first for rank 2 groups. General hint: consider how fixed sets (walls) transform under conjugation.

Comment: Identical question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872965/i-would-like-to-show-that-all-reflections-in-a-finite-reflection-group-w-lan